# OCS Inventory agent doesn't connect to the server

Tags: ocs-inventory-ng

I run GLPI and OCS Inventory NG server on a VM using the web port 7877. In another VM with Ubuntu, I installed OCS Inventory agent using the web port 5566. This is supposed to synchronize and send information about the machine to server but when I ran `ocsinventory-agent`, even as root, I get a message like this:

```
[error] Cannot establish communication : 500 Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:7877 (Connection refused)
```

then I googled this issue and it was talking about SQL problems. Until now it is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the agent is trying to connect to himself (127.0.0.1) instead of the server. You should edit `/etc/ocsinventory/ocsinventory-agent.cfg` to inform the OCS server's IP address, like this:

```
server=10.0.0.1:7877
```

Comment: so i must affect an address to the machine where the OCSNG server is installed ?

Comment: @ihateandroid The agent finds the server by reading the `server` setting in the `/etc/ocsinventory/ocsinventory-agent.cfg` file. The syntax is `server=<SERVER-IP>:<SERVER-PORT>`, where `<SERVER-IP>` is the OCSNG server IP address and `<SERVER-PORT>` is the OCSNG server port (7877). I'm not sure this is what you asked for... Maybe something got lost in translation.